# Qual ferramenta utilizar para implementar Realidade Virtual e Realidade Aumentada em Mobile?

Tags: framework

Estou começando agora a mexer com realidade aumentada e realidade virtual para desenvolver um aplicativo mobile e gostaria de saber quais são os frameworks/ferramentas utilizadas atualmente e seus prós e contras.

Muito obrigada!

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a ajuda for muito simples ainda é possível fazer nos comentários.

Comment: Obrigada pela indicação do Guia! Está fora do escopo mesmo.